# C++ List Iterator Incompatible while Printing a list

Tags: c++, iterator

Well guys, I've been looking for an answer to this error but I haven't got a specific one for my case.
I have a class User, each User has its own list of Computers, the class Computer is composed by these three classes ( Operative Sistem, Memory, and Processor). So Computer has its own toString that calls the specific toString from its components named above.

So...User has his atribute list computerList;

In other class, that I called Controler, I have a function for printing the computer list from a specific user. 
Here is my function:

```
void printComputerList(User* u){
    list<Computer*>::iterator itr;
    for(itr=u->getComputerList().begin(); itr!=u->getComputerList().end(); itr++){
        cout<<(*itr)->toString(); //(*itr) calls its own toString implemented in the class Computer
    }
}
```

So, when I'm running the program, when I choose to print the list that I've already filled
I get the error from the title.
I think it is maybe some kind of confusion between the totrings ?

PD: I can post the rest of the code if it is necesary

Thanks!

Comment: Does `getComputerList()` return reference or value?

Comment: So it will not work. You create temporary lists on stack, get iterator and destroy list.

Comment: Code is always preferable to English description. English is not exact and this kind of thing you need to be exact on. C++ is all about the types. We have no information about the types so as it stands this is unanswerable. A compilable runnable example (with just enough code to show the error) would be best.

Comment: yes, the reason I did't posted more code is because it is a big program, well, for posting it it is big, even between User.cpp, Controler.cpp and Computer.cpp, but if I can get some help, there is no problem on posting the rest of the code

Comment: And as an aside OP, stop using raw pointers in a list like that.  At least use smart pointers so you don't have to deallocate everything yourself.

Comment: You should try to isolate the problematic code into a self contained example that reproduces the problem, because if you post all of the original code, most of it will be irrelevant to the problem and will obscure things. In any case, the issue seems to be solved in the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

There is (at least) one problem with temporary list. Fixed version would look like:

```
void printComputerList(User* u){
  list<Computer*> const computers = u->getComputerList();
  list<Computer*>::const_iterator it = computers.begin();
  while (it != computers.end())
  {
    cout << (*it)->toString(); //(*it) calls its own toString implemented in the class Computer
    ++it;
  }
}
```

Are you sure, that pointers on list are valid (non-null, not dangling ones)?

Comment: damn it doesn't crash anymore but now it doesn't print anything, and I think I'm not filling the list properly, because after pushing back Computer to the list, u->getComputerList().size() shows 0

Comment: I guess, that you pass list by value to some filling function (so get temporary copy), push element to the copy, destroy copy at filling function exit, while original list is still empty. Am I right?